# CakePHP: SaveAll() and hasMany data replace problem

Tags: cakephp, save, has-many

I made one big form with many associations hasMany/HABTM. All is workin great on creating (!). When updating all is working nice too, but in tables where association is hasMany, data is not updated or replaced, but just inserted. This brings many rows with trash data. How can I make saveAll() do the update/replace in hasMany fields:

Model:

```
class MainModel extends AppModel {

  var $hasAndBelongsToMany = array(
    'HABTMModel1',
    ...
    'HABTMModeln',
  );

  var $hasMany = array(
    'Model1' => array(
      'dependent' => true
     ),
     ...
    'Modeln' => array(
      'dependent' => true
    ),
  );
}
```

One of the problematic hasMany models look like:

```
class Model1 extends AppModel {

  var $belongsTo = array(
    'MainModel'
  );
}
```

And his table have:

```
id <- Primary key, auto increment, int (11)
main_model_id <- Foreign_key int (11)
name <- text field, string
```

The $this->data is looking like:

```
array(
  [MainModel] => array(
    'id' => 123
    *** aditional data named identicaly to table fields (working great)***
  ),
  [Model1] => array(
    [0] => array(
      [name] => Test1
    ),
    [2] => array(
      [name] => Test2
    ),
  ),
  *** all other models ***
);
```

Model1 table results after first creating and after updating:

```
id        main_model_id        name
--------------------------------------------------------------
11        306                 Test1
12        306                 Test2
13        306                 Test1  (Thease are dublicates)
14        306                 Test2  (Thease are dublicates)
```

What can I do to update/replace data in hasMany and not insert new values un edit using saveAll ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So I made not so beautiful, but working:

```
// If edit, then delete data from hasMany tables based on main_model_id
if(isset($this->data['MainModel']['id']) && !empty($this->data['MainModel']['id'])) {
  $conditions = array('main_model_id' => $this->data['MainModel']['id']);

  // Delete Model1
  $this->MainModel->Model1->deleteAll($conditions, false);

  ...
  all other models
  ...
}

$this->MainModel->saveAll($this->data);
```

Answer (score 3):

In the view, just put hidden input for all the Model1, Model2 ids

> ```
> echo $form->create('MainModel');
> echo $form->hidden('Model1.0.id');
> // more stuffs...
> echo $form->end('Save');
> ```

You probably specify the 'fields' for Model1, Model2 to have only 'name'. That's why $this->data looks like that. So just add 'id' to that.

Comment: Nope, adding echo $this->Form->hidden('Model1.0.id'); don't do the trick :( In my case 'id' is empty because data is gotten from json after parsed with javascript and so on (long hard road where is no id only main_model_id), so problem is actual :(

Comment: you got the data originally from the MainModel->find() method, right? That's where you specify to include the id.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the `id` field for your hasMany model too e.g.

```
array(  
 [MainModel] => array(
    [id] => 123
    *** aditional data named identicaly to table fields (working great)***   ), 
  [Model1] => array(
    [0] => array(
      [id] => 1,
      [name] => Test1
    ),
    [2] => array(
      [id] => 2
      [name] => Test2
    ),   ),   *** all other models *** );
```

Comment: Thanks for your ansert! But, there is no possibility to delete all data based on main_model_id (as in HABTM)? For this case it is tricky to got and set Model1.id. It will be much easier if tehre would be possibility to update/replace data based on main_model_id. It is possible?

Comment: It's not possible, as without the ids there is no way to identify the records correctly.

Comment: Maybe there are possibility to specify SQL queries using saveAll? It is very hard work to insert 'id' in view/controller.

Comment: So.. I made it for one model. Now data is the same as you wroted. Yes it is not creating dublicate entries for each save now. BUT! Only when I don't change the data!!! If (i have checkboxes for years 2010, 2011, 2012, 2013) I edit data where all 4 years are set, so in table I have 4 records. Now I uncheck last one (2013) so to saveAll is going only 3 array elements. And.. nothing changes.. Cake is not deleting one extra record. How can Cake delete all records based on main_model_id if it can not update as I need?